# Как при клике на img присвоить его src другому элементу img

Tags: html

Обыскал весь интернет... Не нашёл такого скрипта, при нажатии на мини-фото оно появляется внизу в виде большого фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(".small-img").click(function() {
  $(".big-img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

```css
.small-img-wrap img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.big-img-wrap img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-img-wrap">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff0000/000000" class="small-img" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff00ff/000000" class="small-img" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffff00/000000" class="small-img" alt="">
</div>
<div class="big-img-wrap">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/230x230" class="big-img" alt="">
</div>
```

Демо тут [тык](https://allshoes.com.ua/products/ryukzak-converse-chuck-taylor-all-star-bag-red-10003335-a03)

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: @Air Да я пробовал уже и вытащить функцию эту, искал в интернете как реализовать, не нашёл...

Comment: первое что пришло в голову - держать по две картинки, маленькую и большую, айдишки связать в объект, кликнутый объект - ключ, объект для показа - значение. и скриптом по клику просто показывать нужный объект.

Comment: @yolosora сложно...

Comment: ну можно не биндить в объекты, раздать верхним картинкам аттрибуты например name, совпадающие с id нижних картинок, по клику брать name объекта и показывать картинку с таким id

Comment: @NoName, там скрипт то если без изысков, в 10 строчек....Ты хотя бы `html css` напиши сам...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/betigocexu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @fanfer спасибо большое!

Comment: А в своем примере тебе, что не нравится?

Comment: @yolosora я тоже не понимаю о чем речь. Что-то какой-то эльфийский.

Answer (score 0):

Даже если посмотреть поросто иходный код то можно понять логику где все просто и понятно релизировано. Обычный отрывок HTML:

```
<img class="img-min" src="small_img_link" onclick="document.getElementById('photo_2').src = 'big_img_link';" alt="img alt" title="img title">
```

А вот JS:

```
    $(function(){
 var defp =  $('#photo_2').attr('src');
 $('select[name=variant]').live('change', function(){
  var opt = $(this).find('option:selected')||$(this).find('option:first'),
  newp = opt.data('image');
  $('#photo_2').attr('src', (newp ? ''+newp:defp));
 }).change();
});


  $(function(){
 var defp =  $('#photo').attr('src');
 $('select[name=variant]').live('change', function(){
  var opt = $(this).find('option:selected')||$(this).find('option:first'),
  newp = opt.data('image');
  $('#photo').attr('src', (newp ? ''+newp:defp));
 }).change();
});



 // Выбор варианта
$('select[name=variant]').live('change', function(){
    price = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');

 //$('#photo').attr('src', $(this).find('option:selected').data('image'));
 compare_price = '';
    if(typeof $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-compare-price') == 'string')
        compare_price = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-compare-price');

    $(this).closest('form.variants').find('.prc-new').html(price);
    $(this).closest('form.variants').find('.prc-old').html(compare_price);
    return false;

});
```

Кодер у них хороший, все коментировал. Дальше смотри сам, не советую юзать чужой код, лучше сам попробуй написать. Если нужно хотя бы примерно как выглядит, пиши, хотя тут все ясно.

Comment: что-то не срабатывает...

Comment: @NoName, https://pastebin.com/b2SN2drn пример. images_small - дать маленький размер в стилях. image_big - соответственно большой размер. Другое думаю понятно как реализовать особенно если страницу генерирует РНР